# How to avoid detecting click on dropdown inside div if i have click event on div?

Tags: angular

I have this html structure:

```
<div *ngFor="test  of tests" (click)="selectItem(test)">
   <div>{{test.number}}</div>
   <div>
      <select (change)="selectGroup(group)">
            <option *ngFor="let destination of groupDestinations" 
            [(value)]="destination.code">{{destination.displayname}}</option>     
     </select> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Problem is when i change select it detects as click and then it call method `selectItem`. Any suggestion how can i avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$event.stopPropagation()` to prevent the event from bubbling any further up the DOM.

```
<select (change)="selectGroup(group)" (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
   ...   
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add a condition like so

```
<select 
  (change)="selectGroup(group)"
  (click)="selectClicked = true"
  (focus)="selectClicked = true"
  (blur)="selectClicked = false"
>
```

In your TS

```
selectItem(value) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    if(!this.selectClicked) {/* do your stuff */}
  });
}
```

Worth the try !